# Django - link to url from different app in same project

Tags: python, django

I am making a Django project with multiple apps and therefore multiple urls.py files. I am trying to an app for user accounts into a project with apps for the shop, cart, and orders. Specifically, I want to link the account/ pages back to the shop

Main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
url(r'^cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
url(r'^orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]
```

Urls.py for account/:

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
url(r'^logout-then-login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',name='logout_then_login'),
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

]
```

Here is the template I am using for the account page

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <span class="logo">Rachel's Stuff</span>

    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <ul class="menu">
        <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
          <a href="{% url "dashboard" %}">My dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
          <a href="{% url 'shop' %}">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
          <a href="#">People</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="user">
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        Hello {{ request.user.first_name }},
        <a href="{% url "logout" %}">Logout</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url "login" %}">Log-in</a>
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I want to link from 127.0.0.1:8000/account/ back to http://127.0.0.1:8000, which defaults to the main storefront:

```
<li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
      <a href="{% url 'shop' %}">Home</a>
</li>
```

But I get an error:

> Reverse for 'shop' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
>
> Request Method:    GET
>
> Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/
>
> Django Version:    1.8.6
>
> Exception Type:    NoReverseMatch
>
> Exception Value:
> Reverse for 'shop' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not >found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

How can I link back to the main shop page (127.0.0.1:8000/) when I'm already in the account namespace? Sorry if I used any terms wrong.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your input. I still get the same error when I change 'shop' to 'cart' though, and  I do have cart/ in the urls file. Also, under this url scheme, would there be a way to link back to the main shop page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong url name (`shop`) to reverse. Have a look at `shop/urls.py` file and see the actual name of the `^$` path. As there is already a namespace defined it should be reversed as `shop:<your url name here>`.

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    ]

Comment: it should be `product_list` then, reverse that instead of `shop`, should solve it.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for typos

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the same error. 

>Reverse for 'product_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Edit: `shop:product_list` works

Comment: Oh sorry, there is also namespace, try `shop:product_list`